# Fastapi form get only the submitted fields with a defined Form model

Tags: fastapi

So the issue im having, in my post/put route i only want to capture the fields the client(user) sent to the api.
Since "None" is a valid option to set a field to blank, but i would like updates to have "optional" fields. If a field is submitted then to set its value to `null`

(this is obviously an over simplified example)

```py
class MyResponse(BaseModel):
    message: str = None

# setting the Form()'s default to None makes it optional
@dataclasses.dataclass
class MyForm():
    name: str = Form(None)
    description: str = Form(None)

@router.put("/{item_id}")
async def create_an_instance(
    item_id: Annotated[int, Path(title="The ID of the item to get")],
    form: MyForm= Depends()
) -> MyResponse:
    response = MyResponse()

    print(item_id)
    print(form)

    return response
```

(It's very convenient to have it like this (the dataclass of Form fields and Depends in the def parameters) than to have `name=Form(), description=Form()` since values might overlap with
dependencies etc)

This works perfectly for having optional fields and form is populated with name and description.

Now for my plea for assistance, i would like it that if you submit only name that the `form.name` has the field even if you submitted a blank value but not to include `description`. ie:

As far as the client is aware, it only sends the fields it intends updating. It would be very painful to have an endpoint to update every field for instance.

```
--name = "a"
--description = "b"

result: {"name":"a","description":"b"}
```

```
--name = "a"
--description = ""

result: {"name":"a","description":null}
```

```
--name = "a"

result {"name":"a"}
```

```
--name = ""

result: {"name":null}
```

```
--name = ""
--description = ""

result: {"name":null,"description":null}
```

In theory, it submits an empty value, so `--data-urlencode 'name='` which "should" default to `name=""` but it's been turned into `None` automatically. And if a value isnt set, then that field uses the default value, which is `None` to make the field "optional" in the docs.

So even if i did do a check on the `MyForm` to see if the value is `None` then to skip it, but that would mean that i can never really set the "value" of that field to null (which is a valid state - user sets a value for bio, user wants to clear bio type thing).

I know the immediate knee jerk reaction will be to say "put / post the entire state every time", it's however more convenient to have partial data, as in have a front end that only submits "changed" values. or have multiple places in the interface submit partial parts to the profile.

i thought of setting some random default value on the `Form("i_wasnt_included")` and then to check for only the fields that don't have 'i_wasnt_included' but that messes up with the openapi docs and doesn't allow the field to be "optional" anymore.
Setting `name: Optional[str] = Form("i_wasnt_included")` results in a field type wasn't supplied box on the api docs page.

The other issue is that i cant change the api to use json data instead since its being slotted into an existing eco system and all clients already post as `x-www-form-urlencode` - (it would literally be easier to ditch fastapi entirely than to "change" the way things are sent to the api just because of this stupid "little" thing)

Basically something like:

```php
$values = array();
// probs more correct way to do it than isset() but i havent done php in a while so not too phased
if (isset($_POST['name']){
    $values['name'] = $_POST['name']
}
if (isset($_POST['description']){
    $values['description'] = $_POST['description']
}

echo json_encode($values);
```

It still however needs to still show up in the openapi docs and say that both `name: str` and `description: str` are optional and available to be submitted.

---

The Fastapi Form has these parameters for what its worth (maybe im missing a cool option in it)

```py
Form(
    default=default,
    default_factory=default_factory,
    media_type=media_type,
    alias=alias,
    alias_priority=alias_priority,
    validation_alias=validation_alias,
    serialization_alias=serialization_alias,
    title=title,
    description=description,
    gt=gt,
    ge=ge,
    lt=lt,
    le=le,
    min_length=min_length,
    max_length=max_length,
    pattern=pattern,
    regex=regex,
    discriminator=discriminator,
    strict=strict,
    multiple_of=multiple_of,
    allow_inf_nan=allow_inf_nan,
    max_digits=max_digits,
    decimal_places=decimal_places,
    example=example,
    examples=examples,
    openapi_examples=openapi_examples,
    deprecated=deprecated,
    include_in_schema=include_in_schema,
    json_schema_extra=json_schema_extra,
    **extra,
)
```

---

TL;DR how can i give a list of fields that "can" be submitted, and retrieve the values of only the fields that WERE
submitted even if they are blank

Comment: there is a handy `await request.form()` which returns the raw submitted data. but that would require a Request dependency on every def that i want to use this on, and a function like `def return_form_fields_submitted(request:Request, form: MyForm):` in the body. as a last resort i'll have a look at that. would be nicer if the dataclass of form fields could have a Depends for the request and compare the request.form to itself and only return the fields submitted

Answer (score 0):

a possible solution:

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass
class InstanceForm():
    name: str = Form(None)
    description: str = Form(None)
    type_id: TypeIdEnum = Form(None)
    municipality_id: str = Form(None)
    host: str = Form(None)
    ip: str = Form(None)
    remotedb_schema: str = Form(None)
    remotedb_port: int = Form(None)
    remotedb_database: str = Form(None)
    syncdb_database: str = Form(None)
    coms_portal_id: int = Form(None)

async def submitted_form_fields(request: Request) -> list:
    fields = await request.form()
    return list(fields.keys())
    

@router.post("")
async def create_an_instance(
    user=authorization(),
    form: InstanceForm = Depends(),
    fields: list = Depends(submitted_form_fields)
) -> InstancePostResponse:
    response = InstancePostResponse()
    
    values = dataclasses.asdict(form)
    values = {k: values[k] for k in fields if k in values}
    
    response.instance = await service.create(values)
    return response
```

not sure if this is the "best" way or most re-usable way...

> there are 10 ways to skin a cat in programing, but 200 ways the cat skins you instead